# Jest mock module.exports module and count called times

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have some dependency in the tested module.

`sendResponse.js`:

```js
module.exports = function sendResponse(res, data) {
   res.send(data);
};
```

`testedModule.js`:

```
const login = require('.../sendResponse');

exports.postLogin = withServerErrorHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const { email, password } = body;
    const user = await login(email, password);
    return sendResponse(res, user);
});
```

And I want to mock **sendResponse** module and count its calls.

```
const testedModule = require('.../testedModule');

jest.mock('.../sendResponse', () => jest.fn());

const sendResponse = require('.../sendResponse');

describe('testedModule', () => {
    const res = {
      //..
    };
    const req = {
      //..
    };

    describe('Authentication', () => {

        test('should pass', async (done) => {
            await testedModule.postLogin(req, res);
            expect(sendResponse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            done();
        });
    })
});
```

Unfortunately, Jest always gives me that result, It looks like Jest jest spy on `jest.fn()` function, not specific ref. How can I deal with it?

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's confusing that it's called `sendResponse` in one place and `login` in another. It's unknown how `withServerErrorHandler` works. From what you posted, it really wasn't called, otherwise it would say that it's not a spy or else.. Also, `async (done)` is a mistake, don't use `async` and `done` together. *It looks like Jest jest spy on jest.fn() function, not specific ref* - you shouldn't interpret this error message literally, it means that this is an anonymous spy.

Comment: Where does the `withServerErrorHandler` function come from?